# Turning issues on 96toyota truck

Tags: toyota

I have a 96 Toyota T100 SR5. When I turn to the extreme left it's almost as if the truck is pushing the tires instead of turning.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it in 4-wheel drive? If 4-wheel drive is engaged you will notice a lot of friction in tight turns because it will be dragging some of the tires.